# Get facebook page access_token appcelerator arg missing

Tags: facebook-graph-api, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

I have this for trying to get page access token from facebook.

I am doing this with appcelerator titanium.

```
 Ti.Facebook.requestWithGraphPath(Titanium.App.Properties.getString("sidnamn"), {fields: 'access_token'}, function(resp) {
    if(resp.access_token) {
        Ti.API.info(resp.access_token);

        }   });
```

When i run this i get this error:

message = "Invalid number of arguments to function. expected 4 arguments, received: 3  in -[FacebookModule requestWithGraphPath:] (FacebookModule.m:440)";

So what have i missed?

Comment: Titanium.App.Properties.getString("sidnamn")  is PageID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
argument one = target
argument two = data
argument three = method (POST/GET)
argument four = callback
```

My answer does not address the quality of your target or data, but that your 3rd argument is NOT POST/GET

Comment: My good sir. You're right of course.  But now i have another dilemma.       `Ti.Facebook.requestWithGraphPath('/'+ Titanium.App.Properties.getString("sidnamn"), {fields: 'access_token'}, 'GET', function(resp) {
        if(resp.access_token) {
         alert(resp.access_token);

           } else {
            if (resp.error) {
                alert(resp.error);
            } else {
                alert("Unkown result");
            }
        }
    });
 
 });`

Comment: I get "Unkown result" when i run that.  Do i need to parse something from json to get the access_token?  How can i run this to see the json that it returns so i know how to parse it?

Comment: ` Ti.Facebook.requestWithGraphPath('/'+ Titanium.App.Properties.getString("sidnamn"), {fields: 'access_token'}, 'GET', function(resp) {
        if(resp.success) {
         data = JSON.parse(resp.result);
         alert(data);

           } else {
            if (resp.error) {
                alert(resp.error);
            } else {
                alert("Unkown result");
            }
        }
    });
 
 });`         will get med the pageID How can i get the page token?